# Why compiler doesn't generate warnings for negative value with size_t?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, unsigned-integer, size-t

In the following code, I have used `size_t` as an function argument and passed negative value. I have compiled program on GCC(Linux) using following command.

```
g++ -Wall size.cpp -o size
```

GCC compiled successful without warning, but the results are not what I expect:

```
size_t : 18446744073709551615
int : -1
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

void func1(size_t i) 
{
  std::cout << "size_t : " << i << std::endl;
}

void func2(int i) 
{
  std::cout << "int : " << i << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{
  func1(-1);
  func2(-1);
  return 0;
}
```

Why compiler doesn't generate warnings for negative value with `size_t`?

Comment: `size_t` is an unsigned type.

Comment: I suggest you learn a little about [*two's complement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement), which is a (and the most common) way to encode negative integers.

Comment: @Some programmer dude Why doesn't compiler generate warning for negative value with size_t?

Comment: What did you expect? Edit your question, please.

Comment: You can add a warning for this with `-Wconversion` in `gcc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `size_t` is always unsigned in C++:

> The type `size_t` is an implementation-defined unsigned integer type that is large enough to contain the size in bytes of any object.

> Why doesn't compiler generate warning for negative value with size_t?

Because assigning `size_t` a negative value invokes a signed-to-unsigned conversion, which is well-defined:

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [*Note:* In a two’s complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is no truncation). —*end note*]

Comment: There are a lot of well-defined operations that yield warnings. E.g. `if(test = 1)` gives `warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]` at least with Clang C++ compiler. So being well-defined isn't a sufficient condition for not generating a warning.